# Count the number of ways to place $6$ distinct balls in $4$ distinct bins

Tags: combinatorics

Count the number of ways to place $6$ distinct balls in  $4$ distinct bins

My solution:

$6 * 6 * 6 * 6 = 1024$

Correct answer is: $3016$

Any good ideas? :P

Comment: $6^4=1296$ BTW. $1024$ is a power of $2$ so has no factors $3$.

Answer (score 4):

It should be $4^6 = 4096$. Either the answer is wrong or the question is wrongly formulated.

Comment: Correct. The different result may depend on the meaning given to "place", that is which configurations are considered different.

Comment: Well, it says that both bins and balls are distinct. You can imagine it like each ball and each bin had different colour.

Comment: Even if they are considered different, how on earth will the cases decrease as given by the "correct" answer by OP?